# Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 not showing current Git branch

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have two computers, both have Visual Studio 2015 Community installed. Both Visual Studio has Update 1 installed too...

The moment I update my Visual Studio to Update 1, I notice there is a nice Git branch status indicator at the bottom right of the Visual Studio status bar (shown below):

**1st Computer**

[image: 1st computer]

However, there is no such status on my other computer, both are running the same version of visual studio... I have spent an hour scratching my head trying to get the status to appear..

**2nd Computer**

[image: 2nd computer]

How do I get that Git status bar?

Comment: compare the installed extensions.

Comment: I did notice there was a separate git update but I don't know if that fixes it.

Comment: Well..., to be fair I did update my Github Desktop (which in turns update Git), uninstall Resharper, restart.. etc but nothing works... until I repaired visual studio installation as explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it by "repairing" my Visual Studio installation... I think it re-installs everything..

[image]

Comment: I had a new installation of VS 2015 Update 1 and it was missing the menu. Just repaired it and it is there. This is the actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following checkbox is selected when you install VS:

[image: VS Update 1 Installation Features]

Comment: This didn't work for me. Repairing the install did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In the second instance, it's possible that you weren't connected to a git repository. The visibility of the branch switcher depends on whether there is an active repository, so if you were disconnected from a repository in Team Explorer in the second instance, it would not show up.

If you find that you are connected to a git repository in TE and the switcher is not visible, do report the problem through the Send Feedback button in the upper right corner of Visual Studio.

I hope you've found this new branch status and switcher useful!

Comment: I don't think I was simply disconnected.. the 2nd computer is my main development machine.. I have tons of projects in there.. besides.. the moment I repaired the installation the branch status appears... *wink*.. oh!.. I do love the branch status!..