# Visual Studio 2015 Git Settings show There are no available settings

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to setup Visual Studio 2015 with Git, but when I go to Team Explorer > Home > Settings, I expect to see Git Settings but I see There are currently no available settings. Did anyone get this kind of issue?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you forgot to install Git tools for visual studio https://visualstudio.github.com/index.html and you need to install them (not GitHub extension but git for windows as you can see in the second section of the page provided in the link). To make sure you installed them correctly try to repair it following the steps in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34248113/visual-studio-2015-update-1-not-showing-current-git-branch)**

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2019 there is a separate Menu for Git.
But Event you Open Team Explorer > Home > Setting --> Shows There are currently no available settings.
So Come back to Home> you can see tools and commands for git source are now in their own tool window.
Click on : Open Git Changes

for more info check this out: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/announcing-the-release-of-the-git-experience-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

Mohessaid, I did not have to install Git tools.

Solution - 
All I did was right click on Project in Visual Studio > Source Control >Add to Source Control, and then on going to Team Explorer > Home > Settings, I could see Git Settings .

Only once the Project is committed locally using Visual Studio's inbuilt Source Control, Visual Studio allows you to set up connection with third party Source Control/Version Control plugins like GIT.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could try the Manage connections in team explorer.
It's the green plug at the top in team explorer next to the home button.